# Why is data assigned to the cluster reducing with the number of clusters?

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, cluster-analysis, k-means

This is a sample of the code I am using to cluster time series data. My data is 12153 samples with the same length.

When I cluster my data I realize that the data samples assigned the cluster is reduced by the number of clusters. For example when the clusters are two, the assignment has only 12151 samples. when the cluster is 3 the assignment has 12150 and so on and so forth. I can't figure why this is happening. Is there something I am doing wrong in my code below?

```
def k_means_clust_eucl(self, data, initial_centroids):
            '''
            k-means clustering algorithm for time series data.
            using  Euclidean distance
            '''
            # create random centroids
            while True:
                orig = [i for i in range(12153)]
                self.new_centroids = deepcopy(self.centroids)
                # print('iteration ' + str(self.i))
                # assign data points to clusters
                self.assignments = {}
                # print('while_clustering :', len(data))
                for ind, i in enumerate(data):
                    min_dist = float('inf')
                    closest_clust = None
                    for c_ind, j in enumerate(self.centroids):
                        cur_dist = self.euclid_dist(i, j)
                        if cur_dist < min_dist:
                            min_dist = cur_dist
                            closest_clust = c_ind
                    if closest_clust in self.assignments:
                        self.assignments[closest_clust].append(ind)
                        if ind in orig:
                            orig.remove(ind)
                        else:
                            print(ind)
                    else:
                        print('not in assignment')
                        self.assignments[closest_clust] = []
                print(orig)
```

Comment: it could be possible that not all data points are being clustered. Some are left out and treated as outliers. Did you perform any sort of data preprocessing first or did you directly applied a clustering algorithm on the data?

Comment: I normalized my data before clustering

Comment: did you check for outliers? use a boxplot to visualize the outliers in the normalized data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you forget to put the *first* point of each cluster into the newly created cluster.

Instead, after the first point, your cluster is `[]`.